# How to split array into two different array

Tags: php, arrays, slice

How to split array into two different array and return both. here my array is $input , it may contain any number of element.

for example:

```
$input = array ('onex','twox','threex','fourx','fivex','sixx','sevenx','eightx','ninex');
```

I want to split my `'$input'` array into two different array `'$number1'` and `'$number2'` .

1)if `$input` array with even element then split into 2 equal element arrays.

2)if `$input` array with odd element then `'$number1'` is always 1 element greater than `'$number2'` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for it.

```
$new_arrays = array_chunk($input, ceil(count($input)/2));
$number1 = $new_arrays[0];
$number2 = $new_arrays[1];
```